# Android play video problem : Device Specific

Tags: android, video, playback

I used the following code to play the video. It is working properly.

```
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "words/"+videoname);
Uri video = Uri.parse(f.getAbsolutePath());            

videoView.setVideoURI(video);

videoView.start();
```

But sometimes a few specific files starts to play and almose at the end of the video, it is giving error with following msg.

```
Cannot play video
Sorry, this video cannot be played
```

This is happening only when I am trying it Motorola Droid.

In the logcate it is giving following error.

```
04-16 11:46:12.244: WARN/MediaPlayer(7541): info/warning (1, 44)
04-16 11:46:12.244: INFO/MediaPlayer(7541): Info (1,44)
04-16 11:46:12.244: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(7541): getMetadata
04-16 11:46:12.268: DEBUG/AudioHardwareMot(7788): AudioMgr:Output 0xb538 exiting standby
04-16 11:46:14.018: WARN/AudioSystem(7112): AudioFlinger server died!
04-16 11:46:14.018: WARN/AudioSystem(7112): AudioPolicyService server died!
04-16 11:46:14.018: INFO/ServiceManager(1040): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
04-16 11:46:14.018: INFO/ServiceManager(1040): service 'media.player' died
04-16 11:46:14.018: INFO/ServiceManager(1040): service 'media.camera' died
04-16 11:46:14.018: INFO/ServiceManager(1040): service 'media.audio_policy' died
04-16 11:46:14.018: WARN/MediaPlayer(7541): MediaPlayer server died!
04-16 11:46:14.018: ERROR/MediaPlayer(7541): error (100, 0)
04-16 11:46:14.018: ERROR/MediaPlayer(7541): Error (100,0)
04-16 11:46:14.018: DEBUG/VideoView(7541): Error: 100,0
04-16 11:46:14.557: INFO/(7802): ServiceManager: 0xad80
```

But the same file is playing without any problem in other device. What may the problem?

Comment: Happens to me at the beginning of videos on the N-S. Not all videos - just some.

Comment: Played fine after restarting the phone :(

Comment: i think it is better if you pinpoint what kind of files you're having problem in playing. Maybe, the device hw and sw decoder doesn't fully support those files.